# Ada with Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, editor, ada

I'm just starting to learn Ada and was wondering if an editor like MVS 2008/2010 can be used? Will MVS detect the GNAT compiler? I have the GNAT GPL compiler but find the GPS editor hard to use (much less intuitive than the MVS editor). The tutorial doesn't explain well how to create a project in GPS.

I'm currently using AdaGIDE which works well, though it's limited in features.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't ever seen any VS addon for Gnat. It would be tough to do for vanilla Gnat, as it isn't compatible with the Microsoft linker. This is more of a gcc vs. Microsoft thing. There is a Gnat .NET port, which [claims to integrate well](http://www.adacore.com/home/products/gnatpro/add-on_technologies/dotnet/) with the Microsoft tools (including VisualStudio). You may have better luck with that.

The other option you have is [ObjectAda](http://www.aonix.com/Ada_Solutions.html). It doesn't use VisualStudio either, but it uses an environment designed to be familiar to VS users. It isn't free, but last I checked its cost was comparable to VisualC++'s. It *does* use the Microsoft linker, so integrating it with VisualStudio should be doable.

Personally I loathe VisualStudio, and do all my editing in Emacs (Even for Microsoft C++ work), but I can see where you are coming from.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll stick to AdaGIDE for now as it's doing its job. I've tried Emacs before when I was looking for a good LaTeX editor but it was a bit clumsy to use. But I understand that Emacs is an excellent editor for many people and can be perhaps the most popular editor of all time.
I was programming C with an old Borland compiler and now I use MVS 2010 which executes much faster and saves me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

VisualAda isn't released yet, but when it is eventually, it will not only integrate GNAT with Visual Studio, but also automatically generate Ada bindings for WinRT components á la what C++/WinRT does for C++.  [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1J1Bc2I-R8&t=12s) and [here is a posting on comp.lang.ada](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.ada/X9oGYceZLmM) of a demo of the unreleased VisualAda.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, we got "Visual Ada" plugin by Alex Gamper:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexGamper.VisualAda

As stated by many others, the add-on is based on gcc/gnat (with all that mingw/msys2 infrastructure) and still not native for VS